# Find all files in all subdirectories of the ".a" type. Like "stackOverFlowQuestion.a"

Tags: xcode, macos, unix, find, .a

I wanted to access all these output files from Xcode, but I don't seem to be able to find some of them. Can someone help me out with a unix command for them?

I need to find all files with the extension `.a`

I tried `find ."*.a"` , `find *"*.a"`, `find "*.a" .` etc. But they always printed the entire list of files. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . -name "*.a"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

ls *.a

ll *.a